# Spring boot enable log for datasource connection such as connection-url, username, password etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I am deploying my boot-app's jar docker image to embedded tomcat server using jenkin and kubernetes. It is throwing an exception-

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

App is being successfully deploy on my locale, for my local setup below are related properties-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&CharSet=UTF-8&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I just want to check on **which url it is trying to connect, by which user & what password** on server while deploying docker image.
Is there any way in spring boot to enable such logs while application is being deploy?

I tried with many of the available option below-

```
spring.datasource.abandon-when-percentage-full
spring.datasource.access-to-underlying-connection-allowed
spring.datasource.alternate-username-allowed
spring.datasource.auto-commit
spring.datasource.catalog
spring.datasource.commit-on-return
spring.datasource.connection-customizer
spring.datasource.connection-customizer-class-name
spring.datasource.connection-init-sql
spring.datasource.connection-init-sqls
spring.datasource.connection-properties
spring.datasource.connection-test-query
spring.datasource.connection-timeout
spring.datasource.data-source
spring.datasource.data-source-class-name
spring.datasource.data-source-j-n-d-i
spring.datasource.data-source-properties
spring.datasource.db-properties
spring.datasource.default-auto-commit
spring.datasource.default-catalog
spring.datasource.default-read-only
spring.datasource.default-transaction-isolation
spring.datasource.driver-class-loader
spring.datasource.fair-queue
spring.datasource.idle-timeout
spring.datasource.ignore-exception-on-pre-load
spring.datasource.init-s-q-l
spring.datasource.initialization-fail-fast
spring.datasource.isolate-internal-queries
spring.datasource.jdbc-interceptors
spring.datasource.jdbc-url
spring.datasource.jdbc4-connection-test
spring.datasource.leak-detection-threshold
spring.datasource.log-abandoned
spring.datasource.log-validation-errors
spring.datasource.log-writer
spring.datasource.login-timeout
spring.datasource.max-age
spring.datasource.max-lifetime
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size
spring.datasource.metrics-tracker-class-name
spring.datasource.minimum-idle
spring.datasource.num-tests-per-eviction-run
spring.datasource.pool-name
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements
spring.datasource.pool-properties
spring.datasource.propagate-interrupt-state
spring.datasource.read-only
spring.datasource.record-metrics
spring.datasource.register-mbeans
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout
spring.datasource.rollback-on-return
spring.datasource.suspect-timeout
spring.datasource.test-on-connect
spring.datasource.thread-factory
spring.datasource.transaction-isolation
spring.datasource.use-disposable-connection-facade
spring.datasource.use-equals
spring.datasource.use-lock
spring.datasource.validation-interval
spring.datasource.validation-query-timeout
spring.datasource.validator
spring.datasource.validator-class-name
spring.datasource.xa
spring.datasource.xa.data-source-class-name
spring.datasource.xa.properties
```